# how to mongodb search nested documents and find exact match field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[records of collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z22J.png)

i have used the below code to find but it showing all the accounts data

`db.getCollection('leads').find({"accounts.status":"suspended"})`

[after search query the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fayl4.png)

i want to search where accounts.status=suspended but the result should show match nested documents under accounts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `$set` with `$filter` after `$match`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "accounts.status": "suspended"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "accounts": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$accounts",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$a.status",
              "suspended"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tS4s83vBP9q)